# Bind DataTemplate TextBlock foreground property to a targeted TextBox foreground property

Tags: xaml

I am trying to figure out a way to allow an Item's TextBlock (contained inside a ListView's DataTemplate) to set it's foreground property by matching it's Text value with a TextBox's Text value (located on the page), then use the TextBox's foreground value to set the Item's foreground property.

To clarify (hopefully):
Each list item would have different foreground colors determined by the TextBox control with the matching Text value.

This get's me 1/2 way without the needed logic to find the specific control that matches.

Instantiated inside a ListView's DataTemplate

```
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="{Binding Foreground, ElementName= P0TextBox}"/>
```

Instantiated in a RelativePanel on the Page:

```
                <TextBox x:Name="P0TextBox" Text="{Binding NewGame.Players[0].Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     Foreground="{Binding Source={StaticResource Player1Color}}"/>
```

This works but associates all (but one item) to the wrong control/color.

**My thoughts so far:**

*Value Converter* - doesn't seem to have access to page elements to locate target TextBox.

*DataTrigger* - can I trigger code that locates the appropriate TextBox and returns it's colorbrush for the List item to use - maybe?

I'd appreciate any thoughts from more learned XAML developers than myself.

Comment: So, I solved my issue by passing the resources through to a value converter and using code in the converter to pass the appropriate brush back to the data repeater. The solution doesn't really address the question I asked, I won't bother to document it here.